# XPath returns null when I remove the prefix

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsi

I am using XPath in Java under Eclipse. I am writing a soap web service, the XML is using prefix and a namespace and I wanted to remove the prefix and only keep the namespace because I prefer a more readable looking XML document.

When I removed the prefixes from XML definition file and tried to query the XML with XPath I started to get null for every node in the XML!

My question is do I have to use a prefix if I want to use XPath? isn't just namespace is enough?

```
<myrequest
    xmlns="http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice Request.xsd">

   <state>     
       <value>demox</value>
```

this is how my XML starts and when I query this with XPath like `XPath.selectSingleNode()` I always receive null from the XPath for every node in it.

```
String myExpression = "myrequest/state/value";  
Document doc = new Document(requestXML);    
Element e = doc.getRootElement();
request.setMybase(getBase((org.jdom.Element) 
            XPath.selectSingleNode(doc,myExpression)));
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete explanation and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XPath 1.0 to select elements in a namespace you need to use a prefix in your XPath expression to qualify element names. So even with the XML being cleaned up to not use a prefix but rather a default namespace declaration in your XPath expression you need to use a prefix bound to the default namespace you have (`http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice`). How you bind a prefix to a namespace URI depends on the XPath API you use, I am not familiar with JDOM, check its API yourself on how to bind prefixes to namespace URIs.

[edit]The method is http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/xpath/XPath.html#addNamespace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29. so choose any prefix you like (e.g. "pf") and do `addNamespace("pf", "http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice")`, then use that prefix in your XPath (e.g. "pf:myrequest/pf:state/pf:value").

Answer (score 3):

**This is the most FAQ on several XPath-related tags**.

Whenever there is a default namespace in an XML document (as in your case), any element name in an XPath expression must be prefixed with a prefix that is bound to this default namespace. The binding is performed in the hosting language of XPath by typically "registering the default namespace" using a specific method/function.

**The reason why this must be done**:

Whenever there is an unprefixed name in an XPath expression, XPath treats this name as belonging to "no namespace".

Here is the normative text from the **[XPath 1.0 W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-tests)**:

"*A QName in the node test is expanded into an expanded-name using the namespace declarations from the expression context. This is the same way expansion is done for element type names in start and end-tags except that the default namespace declared with xmlns is not used: **if the QName does not have a prefix, then the namespace URI is null** (this is the same way attribute names are expanded). It is an error if the QName has a prefix for which there is no namespace declaration in the expression context*".

Therefore, evaluating `/a/b/c` on a document with a default namespace means: select all elements that are in "no namespace" and are named `c`, whose parent is an element named `b` that is in "no namespace", whose parent is the top element of the xml document and it is named `a` and is in "no namespace".

**As all elements in the document are in its default namespace, and not in "no namespace", this XPath expression selects nothing**.

**Solution**:

1. In the API of your XPath engine, register the default namespace and bind to it a prefix (say "x").
2. Now you can and must use this XPath expression: `/x:myrequest/x:state/x:value` instead of `/myrequest/state/value`

Answer (score 1):

> My question is do I have to use a
>   prefix if I want to use Xpath? isnt
>   just namespace is enough?

You don't ***have to use a namespace prefix*** if you want to use XPath.  Just the namespace is enough, but it makes your XPath much more concise, easier to read and maintain if you register and use a namespace prefix.

You ***could*** use an XPath with generic matches for elements (i.e. `*`) with predicate filters that specify the `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` criteria, like this:

```
/*[local-name()='myrequest' 
   and namespace-uri()='http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice'] 
    /*[local-name()='state' 
       and namespace-uri()='http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice']
      /*[local-name()='value' 
         and namespace-uri()='http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice']
```

However, it's much easier to register the namespace and use a namepace-prefix in your XPath.(e.g. `/ws:myrequest/ws:state/ws:value` )